# How do i properly call a function while creating pthread?

Tags: c, pthreads, codeblocks

I am creating a pthread in the main function and calling another function called "PrintHello". the "PrintHello" function should print some messages. My threads are being created but i am guessing my function "PrintHello" isn't being called properly as the messages are not printing.

I have put another print command in "PrintHello" function and that is printing. That means the function is being called. but i can't figure out why the messages aren't printing.

```
char *messages[NUM_THREADS];
struct thread_data
{
    int thread_id;
    int sum;
    char *message;
    };
struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_THREADS];

void *PrintHello(void *threadarg)
{
    printf("I am in PrintHello");
    int taskid , sum;
    char *hello_msg;
    struct thread_data *my_data;
    Sleep(1);
    my_data = (struct thread_data *) threadarg;
    taskid = my_data ->thread_id;
    sum = my_data ->sum;

    hello_msg = my_data ->message;
    printf("Thread %d: %s  Sum=%d\n", taskid , hello_msg , sum) ;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int *taskids[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc, t, sum;
    sum=0;
    messages[0] = "English: Hello World!";
    ..............
    messages[7] = "Latin: Orbis , te saluto!";
for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
    {
        sum = sum + t;
        thread_data_array[t].thread_id = t;
        thread_data_array[t].sum = sum;
        thread_data_array[t].message = messages[t];
        printf("Creating thread %d\n", t);

        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL , PrintHello , (void *) &thread_data_array[t]);
        //rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL , PrintHello , NULL);
        if (rc)
            {
                printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d \n", rc);
                exit(-1);
            }
    }
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The code should print out the hello messages.

Comment: If you add a second loop where you wait for the threads to exit (`pthread_join`), do you get the output then?

Answer (score 1):

I assume what's happening is your application is exiting before your threads have the chance to actually execute fully. Since you are storing each thread handle in the array of `pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];` what you will need to do is upon creation a call to 
[pthread_join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) should be made which will allow the caller thread to be blocked until the thread has executed and returned. You can call `pthread_join` right after you call `pthread_create` or loop through all your handles and call `pthread_join` on each index in your array. If a call to `pthread_join` is made after the creation of each thread individually then a new thread will not spawn until the previous finishes. If you wish to execute them simultaneously then a loop after all the threads have been created would be the better option.

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int *taskids[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc, t, sum;
    sum=0;
    messages[0] = "English: Hello World!";
    ..............
    messages[7] = "Latin: Orbis , te saluto!";
    for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
    {
        sum = sum + t;
        thread_data_array[t].thread_id = t;
        thread_data_array[t].sum = sum;
        thread_data_array[t].message = messages[t];
        printf("Creating thread %d\n", t);

        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL , PrintHello , (void *) &thread_data_array[t]);
        //rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL , PrintHello , NULL);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d \n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    for(int index = 0; index < NUM_THREADS; ++index){
        pthread_join(threads[index],NULL);//Wait for execution of each thread
    }
}
```

You also don't need to call `pthread_exit` in your main. Typically that should be called in the thread you wish to terminate early where the value passed into `pthread_exit` can be retrieved from the second argument of `pthread_join`

Comment: Good advice.  OP should note, however, that if they join each thread immediately after creating it, then they get no actual concurrency.  Creating all the threads first, and then joining them all later, as you also suggest, is the usual approach.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I did point that out in my post. " If a call to pthread_join is made after the creation of each thread individually then a new thread will not spawn until the previous finishes."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. I should have mentioned that i am using Windows. Anyway, i found out the problem. It is happening because of the "sleep" argument. For windows apparently it is different. so i changed my sleep argument to Sleep(1000), which apparently means 1 second in windows and that solved my problem. Thank you for all the replies.

Comment: That doesn't solve the underlying issue of what was pointed out. Sleep just delays execution. Also why would you be using pthread_create on Windows? A Windows API call would be CreateThread or you could use the c++ standard library for threads.